# substr() strange output. what is causing this?

Tags: php, html-entities

So I am using substr to limit how much of a news article I show.  Here is the code:

```
substr(strip_tags($news['content']),0,$content_length) . '...';
```

The problem happens only in a blue moon.. when it tries to cut off near an apostrophe.  I get the following output `Hoye&#...` In this case, the `$news['content']` is `"Hoye's Pharmacy will be closed....."`. The `$content_length` value in this case happens to be 8. Someone suggested trying `mb_substr` but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: How are you confirming that the string is `Hoye's`? Seems to me it's `Hoye&#27;s` instead (or something similar). Please check the raw output, not output as filtered through a browser.

Comment: Yes, I assume this is probably what is happening.. hmm solution?

Comment: Please see: [Wordwrap / Cut Text in HTML string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8494901/367456)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the content contains encoded HTML character entities, and your substring happens to chop the string in the middle of one of them.

e.g.

```
$string = "Hello &amp; Goodbye";
$broken =  substr($string, 0,7); // Hello &a
```

if you view the full string in a browser, it'll translate the encoded entity to its "display" version, so you'll see the real character, but once you chop it half with the substr, you'll get the partial &#xxx portion instead, since it can't be translated.

Comment: Suggested fix: look for the next space after the position and chop there.

Comment: You could decode the string (`html_entity_decode()`) so only 'real' characters are in there, and then use `mb_substr()` on that, so it won't split up unicode characters as `substr()` does. But this could break code farther down the line that's expecting encoded characters that are no longer there.

Comment: tried mb_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($news['content'])),0,$content_length).. no cigar :(