# Wordwrap / Cut Text in HTML string

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, word-wrap

here what i want to do : i have a string containing HTML tags and i want to cut it using the wordwrap function excluding HTML tags.

I'm stuck :

```
public function textWrap($string, $width)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($string);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $elem)
    {
        foreach ($elem->childNodes as $node)
        {
            if ($node->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE)
            {
                $text = trim($node->nodeValue);
                $length = mb_strlen($text);
                $width -= $length;
                if($width <= 0)
                { 
                    // Here, I would like to delete all next nodes
                    // and cut the current nodeValue and finally return the string 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure i'm doing it in the right way at the moment. I hope it's clear...

**EDIT :**

Here an example. I have this text

```
    <p>
        <span class="Underline"><span class="Bold">Test to be cut</span></span>
   </p><p>Some text</p>
```

Let's say I want to cut it at the 6th character, I would like to return this :

```
<p>
    <span class="Underline"><span class="Bold">Test to</span></span>
</p>
```

Comment: You are not doing it right at the moment. A good start could be to learn what `nodeValue` stands for. Next to that XML has child elements, I think you actually want to drop all childs at a certain position. So try to develop how a wordwrap in HTML could actually work. And it's probably worth you add some simple input HTML example so it's more clear into which problems you actually run.

Comment: I have added some code that does something similar (manipulating the DOM based on strings of it's text-only representation) in a somewhat [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8193700/367456) (Question: [Ignore html tags in preg_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8193327/367456)). Hopefully it's helpful, but probably it's a bit much for a start but I think it still can leave some hints.

Comment: @hakre, I added an example. But I don't know how I could drop all child at a certain position...

Comment: I would say first of all you don't know how to find the position where to split the DOM actually. In you example, are the `HTML`, `HEAD` and `BODY` tags auto-generated as it is the case as in HTML 2? Just asking to better understand your example code.

Comment: Do you only want to cut or do you even want to wrap?

Comment: There's no `HTML`, `HEAD` or `BODY` tags. Only `span`, `a`, `p`, `ul`, `ol`, `li` and `img` are available. I have just some text formatted with theses tags. As I put in my code, I think I have to split the DOM when the maximum length of text is reached. In fact i'm new with the DOM lib, I don't know how to cut the DOM properly. I want to wrap the text but also to remove all others children after the last one, in which the text has been wrapped

Comment: So you actually don't want to wordwrap, but you want to cut the HTML string at a certain text position (as in HTML not string position as in a PHP string). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but without breaking any words,that's why I wanted to use the wordwrap function too. Maybe I misunderstood this function

Comment: The PHP [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/wordwrap) function can preserve words. But it is not aware of HTML, just words (not HTML tags, comments etc.). Additionally it only support latin-1 type of character sets IIRC.

Comment: Yeah. At least how could I split the HTML string properly, by removing all children after a certain position ? I am not aware of all DOM functions

Comment: One part would be to split the right `DOMText` node and then remove all following nodes including their children. An [xpath axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) might be useful for that (`following-sibling` and/or `following`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, you first need to find the textual offset where to do the cut.

First of all I setup a `DOMDocument` containing the HTML fragment and then selecting the body which represents it in the DOM:

```
$htmlFragment = <<<HTML
<p>
        <span class="Underline"><span class="Bold">Test to be cut</span></span>
   </p><p>Some text </p>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlFragment);
$parent = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
if (!$parent)
{
    throw new Exception('Parent element not found.');
}
```

Then I use my `TextRange` class to find the place where the cut needs to be done and I use the `TextRange` to actually do the cut and locate the `DOMNode` that should become the last node of the fragment:

```
$range = new TextRange($parent);

// find position where to cut the HTML textual represenation
// by looking for a word or the at least matching whitespace
// with a regular expression. 
$width = 17;
$pattern = sprintf('~^.{0,%d}(?<=\S)(?=\s)|^.{0,%1$d}(?=\s)~su', $width);
$r = preg_match($pattern, $range, $matches);
if (FALSE === $r)
{
    throw new Exception('Wordcut regex failed.');
}
if (!$r)
{
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Text "%s" is not cut-able (should not happen).', $range));
}
```

This regular expression finds the offset where to cut things in the textual representation made available by `$range`. The regex pattern is [inspired by another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2689242/367456) which discusses it more detailed and has been slightly modified to fit this answers needs.

```
// chop-off the textnodes to make a cut in DOM possible
$range->split($matches[0]);
$nodes = $range->getNodes();
$cutPosition = end($nodes);
```

As it can be possible that there is nothing to cut (e.g. the `body` will become empty), I need to deal with that special case. Otherwise - as noted in the comment - all *following* nodes need to be removed:

```
// obtain list of elements to remove with xpath
if (FALSE === $cutPosition)
{
    // if there is no node, delete all parent children
    $cutPosition = $parent;
    $xpath = 'child::node()';
}
else
{
    $xpath = 'following::node()';
}
```

The rest is straight forward: Query the xpath, remove the nodes and output the result:

```
// execute xpath
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$remove = $xp->query($xpath, $cutPosition);
if (!$remove)
{
    throw new Exception('XPath query failed to obtain elements to remove');
}

// remove nodes
foreach($remove as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

// inner HTML (PHP >= 5.3.6)
foreach($parent->childNodes as $node)
{
    echo $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

The full code example is [available on viper codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Fq4IPu) incl. the `TextRange` class. The codepad has a bug so it's result is not properly (Related: [XPath query result order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8195733/367456)). The actual output is the following:

```
<p>
        <span class="Underline"><span class="Bold">Test to</span></span></p>
```

So take care you have a current libxml version (normally the case) and the output `foreach` at the end makes use of a PHP function `saveHTML` which is available with that parameter since PHP 5.3.6. If you don't have that PHP version, take some alternative like outlined in [How to get the xml content of a node as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/999916/367456) or a similar question.

When you closely look in my example code you might notice that the cut length is quite large (`$width = 17;`). That is because there are many whitespace characters in front of the text.  This could be tweaked by making the regular expression drop any number of whitespace in fron t of it and/or by trimming the `TextRange` first. The second option does need more functionality, I wrote something quick that can be used after creating the initial range:

```
...
$range = new TextRange($parent);
$trimmer = new TextRangeTrimmer($range);
$trimmer->trim();
...
```

That would remove the needless whitespace on left and right inside your HTML fragment. The `TextRangeTrimmer` code is the following:

```
class TextRangeTrimmer
{
    /**
     * @var TextRange
     */
    private $range;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $charlist;

    public function __construct(TextRange $range, Array $charlist = NULL)
    {
        $this->range = $range;
        $this->setCharlist($charlist);      
    }
    /**
     * @param array $charlist list of UTF-8 encoded characters
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setCharlist(Array $charlist = NULL)
    {
         if (NULL === $charlist)
            $charlist = str_split(" \t\n\r\0\x0B")
        ;

        $list = array();

        foreach($charlist as $char)
        {
            if (!is_string($char))
            {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Not an Array of strings.');
            }
            if (strlen($char))
            {
                $list[] = $char; 
            }
        }

        $this->charlist = array_flip($list);
    }
    /**
     * @return array characters
     */
    public function getCharlist()
    {
        return array_keys($this->charlist);
    }
    public function trim()
    {
        if (!$this->charlist) return;
        $this->ltrim();
        $this->rtrim();
    }
    /**
     * number of consecutive charcters of $charlist from $start to $direction
     * 
     * @param array $charlist
     * @param int $start offset
     * @param int $direction 1: forward, -1: backward
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    private function lengthOfCharacterSequence(Array $charlist, $start, $direction = 1)
    {
        $start = (int) $start;              
        $direction = max(-1, min(1, $direction));
        if (!$direction) throw new InvalidArgumentException('Direction must be 1 or -1.');

        $count = 0;
        for(;$char = $this->range->getCharacter($start), $char !== ''; $start += $direction, $count++)
            if (!isset($charlist[$char])) break;

        return $count;
    }
    public function ltrim()
    {
        $count = $this->lengthOfCharacterSequence($this->charlist, 0);

        if ($count)
        {
            $remainder = $this->range->split($count);
            foreach($this->range->getNodes() as $textNode)
            {
                $textNode->parentNode->removeChild($textNode);
            }
            $this->range->setNodes($remainder->getNodes());
        }

    }
    public function rtrim()
    {
        $count = $this->lengthOfCharacterSequence($this->charlist, -1, -1);

        if ($count)
        {
            $chop = $this->range->split(-$count);
            foreach($chop->getNodes() as $textNode)
            {
                $textNode->parentNode->removeChild($textNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Codepad Viper is down :(, the source-code of the TextRange and the TextRangeTrimmer class is here as well: https://gist.github.com/gists/1894360/

Comment: The link from hakre on Feb 23 '12 is no longer working. Here's a new link that seems to work: https://gist.github.com/hakre/1894360

Comment: @JonWatson: That's the exact example, correct. Looks like github changed gist URIs, thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

If usage of DOM parsing is not the aim and you need only trancate HTML —
take a look at `cot_string_truncate` function in this **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/macik/93809b6bf85c5b2a95b4)**. It taken from Cotonti CMF.

It's processed plain text or HTML as well. You can set length and choose how to trancate text — exact characters by limit or by word nearest boundary.

It proper treats HTML entities and serial space characters as one (as it viewed in browser) — so your example should work well:

```
$test_str = "<p>
    <span class=\"Underline\"><span class=\"Bold\">Test to be cut</span></span>
</p><p>Some text</p>";

echo cot_string_truncate($test_str, 8);
```

Result:

```
<p>
     <span class="Underline"><span class="Bold">Test to</span></span></p>
```