# regex to match a specific HTML string with any number of spaces inside it

Tags: php, regex

I have code with several lines like this

```
<p> &lt;inset&gt;</p>
```

Where there may be any number of spaces or tabs (or none) between the opening `<p>` tag and the rest if the string. I need to replace these, but I can't get it to work.

I thought this would do it, but it doesn't work:

```
<p>[ \t]+&lt;inset&gt;</p>
```

Comment: Every time you regex some html, Allan Turing stomps on a kitten.

Comment: @MarcB:  Too funny. :-)  There's nothing wrong with using regex on HTML when what you're wanting to do is very simple, though (like this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$html = preg_replace('#(<p>)\s+(&lt;inset&gt;</p>)#', '$1$2', $html);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want true text-trimming for HTML including everything you can encounter like those entitites, comments, child-elements and all that stuff, you can make use of a `TextRangeTrimmer` and `TextRange`:

```
$htmlFragment = '<p> &lt;inset&gt;</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlFragment);
$parent = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
if (!$parent)
{
    throw new Exception('Parent element not found.');
}

$range = new TextRange($parent);
$trimmer = new TextRangeTrimmer($range);
$trimmer->ltrim();

// inner HTML (PHP >= 5.3.6)
foreach($parent->childNodes as $node)
{
    echo $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

Output:

```
<p>&lt;inset&gt;</p>
```

I've both classes in a gist: https://gist.github.com/1894360/ (codepad viper is down).

See as well the related questions / answers:

- [Wordwrap / Cut Text in HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494901/367456)
- [Ignore html tags in preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8193700/367456)

Answer (score -2):

Try to load your HTML string into a DOM tree instead, and then `trim` all the text values in the tree.

http://php.net/domdocument.loadhtml

http://php.net/trim

Comment: That's more a comment than an answer.

Comment: OP said: "_I need to replace these, but I can't get it to work_", and my answer allows them to get rid of the extra whitespace characters as they want. As Marc B said, _Every time you regex some html, Allan Turing stomps on a kitten_.