# How to AppendChild and ReplaceChildin PHP Dom?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

we are working on a project, in which we need to appendChild and ReplaceChild within the PHP DOM, and then save the file.

PHP Code

```
<?php 
$string = '<u>technical/u>';
?>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<div>Stack Overflow is great website for technical professionals.
<p>checking all of the websites</p>
</div>
<h1>Looking something new for a technical professional</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

we just want to replace $string with duplicated words like "technical" is used in and  .

The final HTML code will be

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<div>Stack Overflow is great website for <u>technical</u> professionals.
<p>checking all of the websites</p>
</div>
<h1>Looking something new for a <u>technical</u> professional</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have tried , ` $node = $doc->createElement("para", "as fasd fasd fadsf"); $nodename->appendChild($node);echo $nodename->nodeValue."<br>"`

Comment: You need to split textnodes for this. These operations are not straight forward trivial, but example code does exist here on stackoverflow. One related I know is [Wordwrap / Cut Text in HTML string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8482339/367456) another one is [Ignore html tags in preg_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8193327/367456) which - despite the title - shows how to do that with `DOMDocument` and `DOMText`.